# Eclipse Oxygen/Neon: Unable to build ANT project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am running into an issue. I am trying to build my code which is a legacy one built on Java 1.6. However, when i am trying to build it using ANT with a similar version then run into the JRE version 1.7 or greater is supported. I tried following instructions with Eclipse NEON but no luck.

https://blog.sibvisions.com/2016/06/30/eclipse-neon-with-ant-and-jre6/

I have a Eclipse Oxygen IDE and tried with it too but even it doesn't work. 
The only challenge I can't move to the latest version while building .xml file is because the hosting server supports JDK 1.6 only.

Incase, if there is a way out then please suggest.

P.S:- added the error message in the below comment.

HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE
the JRE version 1.7 or greater is supported"

[image: Error text for ANT]

Comment: Could you please add the error message to your question? You can specify the Java version that should be used to run Ant in the _JRE_ tab in the external tools configuration (_Runtime JRE_).

Comment: This is the error message it shows up "the JRE version 1.7 or greater is supported". Yes, I tried mentioning the 1.6 in the external tools in the ANT build, but it doesn't allow me to run through.

Comment: do you have any thoughts ?

Comment: If the Ant script requires Java 6, you can specify this in _Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations..._, in the _JRE_ tab of the Ant configuration. If this does not fix your problem, add the error message to your question.

Comment: Done, please check

Comment: When, how and where do you get the error message? Is `the JRE version 1.7 or greater is supported` the whole error message? Eclipse Oxygen requires Java 8. Could you please describe step by step how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I get this error as soon as I do Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations..., in the JRE tab of the Ant configuration. I have a legacy code which is compiled on JDK 1.6 so I built the code using Java 1.6 and then mentioned the same in the ANT configuration JRE tab as "1.6" as I have to deploy on the server JBOSS which supports 1.6. However, it doesn't let me build the code ANT using 1.6 as it gives the above error.

Comment: So the error is displayed in the _External Tools Configurations_ dialog, not when running the Ant script? Could you please show a screenshot of the error?

Comment: This is the error message it shows up "the JRE version 1.7 or greater is supported".

Comment: You already said that. But where and when is the message displayed? Please add a screenshot that shows the error message to your question.

Comment: I am not sure how the image will help even though I have mentioned about the error text earlier. However, I have added it now. Please see through above.

Comment: The error message on the screenshot says something different: _JRE version **less than 1.7** is **not** supported_.

Comment: Search the web for `eclipse ant "JRE version less than 1.7 is not supported."`.

Answer (score 2):

The ANT plugin form blog.sibvisions.com was created for Neon or Mars. There's a new plugin available for Oxygen.1. Simply search the blog.

The problem with eclipse is that the standard ANT plugin was created based on Java 7 and it has a version check built-in. It's not possible to use the standard ANT plugin with Java6... So use an older eclipse version or the modified ANT plugin.

I don't know the reason why the original ANT plugin is using Java 7 because the source can be written with Java 6 compatibility without problems. This is what the modified ANT plugin does.